# Batch file not closing with exit command

Tags: batch-file, command-line, exit

I am opening a .net solution in visual studio 2019 using batch command through a batch file like this

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" "D:\Pawan\Projects\MyProj\src\MyProj.sln"
```

and it is working, it opens the project in VS2019 successfully.

The problem is it keeps the command window open and not closing by any of these commands I tried

`exit 0`

`exit /b 0`

`GOTO:EOF`

Any idea?

Comment: Why would `devenv.exe` support those commands?

Comment: Not devenv.exe, I was talking about batch file. I added `exit` commands after the first command in batch file to close it

Comment: Did you close `devenv` if not it will wait.

Comment: @Mark - But I want to open the solution only. That is all I want to do, and so I do not want to close devenv.

Comment: Read `start /?` on unusual ways of starting programs.

Comment: @Mark - Thanks!! the `start` trick worked!

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that your next command (like `EXIT`) isn't run until the previous command finished.
The `START` command without `/WAIT` can help you here, since it returns right away and batch file processing continues while the launched program is still running.

```
START "Launch MyProj" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" "D:\Pawan\Projects\MyProj\src\MyProj.sln"
```